# Updating python version3.6 to python 3.8.1

Tags: raspbian, python, sd-card, python-2.x, pip

currently, my raspberry pi runs python versions 2.7 and 3.6 [by default] and version 3.8.1 [I'm trying to update the current version]
This causes a lot of trouble when I try to install a new package via pip.
For example, I tried to download flask via "pip install flask".
and the package kept failing.
can someone help?
I want to work in the cleanest way possible, and I'm not searching for a quick/temporary heck.

Comment: The distributions use compatible packages for a reason - they are compatible.  I expect you are on your own.

Comment: @joan To be clear, you are saying the new versions of python are incompatible with my current raspberian distribution?

Comment: Check [this link](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/) out.

Comment: actually, @M.Rostami, this is how i downloaded the new python version. did you also follow it and then had bad experience when working with it and pip?

Comment: @Matbrightington Alright, no I didn't follow. Google it, there is a lot of procedure to do that. However, if you had a bad experience as you said, telling them would be the best action you could.

Comment: you are correct, i should try leaving a comment on that forum.

Comment: Please post the [actual commands](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476) which are "causing a lot of trouble". For instance, did you alias `pip` to `pip3.8`?